# Current week Monday is printed

Tags: c#

How can I set to C# property that day is automatically printed as Monday of current week?

```
public DateTime MondayOfCurrentWeek(this DateTime dt) 
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    return new GregorianCalendar().AddDays(today, -((int)today.DayOfWeek) + 1);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Document date - {Document.MondayOfCurrentWeek(DateTime.Now)}");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=net-6.0) property of `DateTime`. Following function would work:

```
DateTime MondayOfCurrentWeek()
{
    int DaysToMonday(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) => dayOfWeek switch
    {
        DayOfWeek.Monday => 0,
        DayOfWeek.Tuesday => -1,
        DayOfWeek.Wednesday => -2,
        DayOfWeek.Thursday => -3,
        DayOfWeek.Friday => -4,
        DayOfWeek.Saturday => -5,
        DayOfWeek.Sunday => -6
    };

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var mondayOfCurrentWeek = now.AddDays(DaysToMonday(now.DayOfWeek));

    return mondayOfCurrentWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you see is that the default "start of the week" is Sunday. I.e. `DayOfWeek.Sunday` is `0` while `DayOfWeek.Monday` is `1`. So in your case, when `var today = DateTime.Now` is a Sunday, `today.DayOfWeek` will return `0`;

If you want a less hard-coded way to get the date for the start of the week, you can do something like this:

```
public DateTime StartOfWeek(
    DateTime dt,
    DayOfWeek weekStart = DayOfWeek.Monday) 
{
    const int totalWeekDays = 7;
    var daysSinceWeekStart = (totalWeekDays - ((int)weekStart - (int)dt.DayOfWeek)) % totalWeekDays;
    return dt.AddDays(-daysSinceWeekStart);
}

// Use it like this:
Console.WriteLine($"Document date - {Document.StartOfWeek(DateTime.Now)}");

// Or, if you want Sunday to be the start of the week:
Console.WriteLine($"Document date - {Document.StartOfWeek(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Sunday)}");
```